# Query using subquery needs longer than same query with fixed data instead of subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, subquery, mariadb

The combined query

```
select a, b from A where a > 5 and b in (select b from B where c = "some")
```

takes about 30 times longer than the fixed query

```
select a, b from A where a > 5 and b in (1, 2, 3)
```

even though

- `select b from B where c = "some"` results in the exact same row set used in the fixed query, `(1, 2, 3)`
- `select b from B where c = "some"` alone takes 0.01s to execute
- `select a, b from A where a > 5` takes 0.3s to execute.

There's an index over (a, b) on A.

Analyzing the combined query:

```
analyze select a, b from A where a > 5 and b in (select b from B)
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: A
         type: range
possible_keys: idx_a_b
          key: idx_a_b
      key_len: 8
          ref: NULL
         rows: 126459
       r_rows: 66181.00
     filtered: 100.00
   r_filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: B
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 2
          ref: A.b
         rows: 1
       r_rows: 1.00
     filtered: 100.00
   r_filtered: 0.09
        Extra: Using where
```

Note that r_rows = 66181 matches `select a, b from A where a > 5`.

Seems like MariaDB uses only the a part of the index and ignores the b's it should be able to get from the subquery in a first step. explain extended shows that MariaDB replaces my query with

```
select b, a from B join A where ((B.b = A.b) and (A.a > 5) and (B.c = "some"))
```

Strange is, if given the fixed set (1, 2, 3), as returned by the subquery, instead of the subquery itself, MariaDB does indeed seem to use both a and b of the index at once, as can be observed by analyzing the fixed query:

```
analyze select a, b from A where a > 5 and y in (1, 2, 3)
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: A
         type: range
possible_keys: idx_a_b
          key: idx_a_b
      key_len: 10
          ref: NULL
         rows: 126459
       r_rows: 59.00
     filtered: 100.00
   r_filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

r_rows = 59 matches the result set size for both queries (the combined one and the fixed one).

How can I get MariaDB to use the same query plan as in the fixed query, using both a and the subquery's b from A's index?

Comment: What version??  There have been improvements in this area.

Comment: 10.1.40-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My brain turned to mush trying to handle B vs b and A vs a, so I changed the table names.

```
select  Y.b, Y.a
    from  X
    join  Y
    where  ((X.b = Y.b)
       and  (Y.a > 5)
       and  (X.c = "some")
           )
```

That query needs

```
X:  INDEX(c, b)
Y:  INDEX(a, b), INDEX(b, a)
```

That way, the Optimizer can be efficient regardless of which table it starts with.  The Optimizer will pick the better table to start with based on statistics for `a` and `c`.  However, unless you turned on "histograms" (MariaDB 10.0 - 10.3; 10.4 has them on by default), the Optimizer may not have the full story.

Comment: Thank you, quite surprising after all. My test run needs 1.18s without new indices, with Y(b, a) 1.08s, with X(c) 0.81s (same with X(c, b)), and using both Y(b, a) and X(c) results in an instant answer.

Comment: @Jojoma - If `c="some"` is unique (or nearly so), then `(c)` is very fast (perhaps faster with `(c,b)`, followed by checking very few rows in the other table (fast because of so few rows to check).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, queries optimize differently.  The query planner knows much more about what you are doing when you have a fixed list of values.

If you have no duplicates in `b`, then `join` often produces a good execution plan:

```
select a.a, a.b
from a join
     b
     on a.b = b.b
where a.a > 5;
```

I would also recommend trying `exists` instead:

```
select a, b
from A
where a > 5 and
      exists (select 1 from B where b.b = a.b) ;
```

And be sure that you have an index on `b(b)`:

```
create index idx_b_b on b(b);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Looking into it I found the "explain extended" command, which shows that MariaDB actually does use a join: `select b, a from B join A where ((B.b = A.b) and (A.a > 5) and (B.c = "some"))` (B.c = "some" being the subquery on B from the initial post). I've edited my question accordingly.